# Spring Data Query Map<String, Integer> non unique result

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring

I have this query to database table:

```sql
SELECT sales_deadline_by_retail AS 'type', COUNT(*) AS 'amount'
FROM (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 3 THEN 'Less 3'
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 7 THEN '4 - 7'
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 15 THEN '8 - 15'
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 30 THEN '16 - 30'
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 60 THEN '31 - 60'
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 120 THEN '61 - 120'
                 WHEN deadline_by_retail > 120 THEN 'More 120'
                 ELSE 'Undefined' END sales_deadline_by_retail
      FROM sales_of_tech
      WHERE seller_id = 'B71E005056AD35EB11E6CD0C7B7CC210'
        and warehouse_id = '9F7E005056AD35EB11E6FD987DF6600C'
        and date between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31 23:59:59') d
GROUP BY sales_deadline_by_retail
```

Spring data query looks like:

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT sales_deadline_by_retail AS 'type', COUNT(*) AS 'amount' FROM " +
            "(SELECT CASE WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 3 THEN 'Less 3' " +
            "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 7 THEN '4 - 7' " +
            "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 15 THEN '8 - 15' " +
            "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 30 THEN '16 - 30' " +
            "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 60 THEN '31 - 60' " +
            "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 120 THEN '61 - 120' " +
            "WHEN deadline_by_retail > 120 THEN 'More 120'' " +
            "ELSE 'Undefined' END sales_deadline_by_retail " +
            "FROM sales_of_tech WHERE seller_id = ?1 and warehouse_id = ?2 and date between ?3 and ?4) d " +
            "GROUP BY sales_deadline_by_retail", nativeQuery = true)
    Map<String, Integer> getGraphByDeadlineByRetail(String sellerId, String jobId, Date start, Date end);
```

Exception on Query call:

```
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 8
```

I know that query did not return a unique result and I try to put data to Map. I know that Map "doesn't true collection", but how can I solve this issue? By the way, I also tried to embed data in the model and create an object in the query itself, but in such cases there were problems with the input and cast of the data to model.

UPDATE 1:
I tried to save data into model like this:

```java
public class PairTypeAmount {
    private String type;
    private int amount;
    // setter and getters
}
```

New query variable and method name:

```java
List<PairTypeAmount> getGraphByDeadlineByRetail(String sellerId, String jobId, Date start, Date end);
```

Error:

```java
No converter found capable of converting from type 
[org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] 
to type [com.iwis.dwhconnector.models.PairTypeAmount]
```

Comment: I did it using SQL query with list<Object> response and then parse it with iter

Answer (score 1):

You can create a POJO that holds type and amount, return that from query. something like:-

```
public class SalesTypeAmount{
  String type;
  int amount;
  //getter, setter etc.
}

Change repo method:-
List<SalesTypeAmount> getGraphByDeadlineByRetail(String sellerId, String jobId, Date start, Date end);
```

Comment: Thank you for idea. Unfortunately, I ran into another problem. Please, check update.

Comment: You need to map POJO with query results. Such as
Use SQLResultSetMapping:-
```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = “test”,
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = SalesTypeAmount.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = “type”)...
                        }
                )
        }
)
@Query(
        query =  <query>,
        resultSetMapping = "test"
)
```
Refer to sections 3, 4 in https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do that in JpaRepository with native query. You can implement your repository method using entity manager like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> postCountByYearMap = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT sales_deadline_by_retail AS 'type', COUNT(*) AS 'amount' FROM " +
         "(SELECT CASE WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 3 THEN 'Less 3' " +
         "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 7 THEN '4 - 7' " +
         "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 15 THEN '8 - 15' " +
         "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 30 THEN '16 - 30' " +
         "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 60 THEN '31 - 60' " +
         "WHEN deadline_by_retail <= 120 THEN '61 - 120' " +
         "WHEN deadline_by_retail > 120 THEN 'More 120'' " +
         "ELSE 'Undefined' END sales_deadline_by_retail " +
         "FROM sales_of_tech WHERE seller_id = ?1 and warehouse_id = ?2 and date between ?3 and ?4) d " +
         "GROUP BY sales_deadline_by_retail", Tuple.class)
         .getResultStream()
         .collect(
              Collectors.toMap(
                   tuple -> ((String) tuple.get("type")),
                   tuple -> ((Number) tuple.get("amount")).intValue()
              )
         );
```